# I am glitching in a bed in Minecraft multiplayer 1.7.2

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am in Minecraft right now, glitching in a bed because I was on top of someone. I tried `/kill` and `/leave`, and none of them work. I am in full screen, so I can't exit or go to the menu. Please, I would love to hear your suggestions.

Comment: alt+tab to another window, ctrl+alt+delete and kill the minecraft process

Answer (score 1):

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>Tab</kbd> to switch programs and get to the desktop, or <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>F4</kbd> to close Minecraft.

Or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>Delete</kbd>, get to the Task Manager and kill the Minecraft process.

If that doesn't work, press and hold the power button on your PC.