# Why can't I destroy blocks?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

After placing a stone pressure plate next to my door (which is also right next to my bed), I went to sleep one night.

When I woke up, I could only see a dark brown/red colour. I saved, exited and then re-entered the world. I discovered I was stuck in my bed or something. I could go backwards and forwards, (by about one block) but then stopped. There was also a wall behind me, which was why I couldn't go back, but in front there was nothing.

I tried destroying my bed, but nothing happened. I put down TNT to blow up me and myself, hoping I would respawn without this glitch. But I got no results, it was still there. I am currently in Survival. I definitely know that I didn't go into Adventure mode because I have a pickaxe and it wouldn't be mining anything... What do I do?

Comment: Wow. I made a new world in creative to see if it did the same. It did. And then when i went to delete my test one I accidentaly deleted my other real world. So i now have no worlds, and even if i did i wouldnt be able to destroy blocks.Great.

Comment: Were you stuck in the head portion of the bed? That would be why you couldn't walk forwards. Did you try walking out the side of the bed?
It's a good idea to keep a bit of space around your bed, so you don't spawn inside blocks, in the future.
I'm not sure why you couldn't break blocks though, except if your head was stuck in something, but you didn't say you were taking suffocation damage...

Comment: Yep, it was the pillow part, but i didn't have space on the sides, so i couldn't walk out the side. I wasn't suffocating though. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @happycake Can you jump out? And can you post a screenshot or video?

Comment: @PrivatePansy this is a different issue presented as an X/Y problem.  He glitched into the ground beneath his bed, and now can't get out (because he can't break any blocks).

Comment: Well i got out by blowing the whole thing up but i still cant destroy blocks. And i accidentally blew up that world anyway. I cant destroy in any world so far.

Comment: Created new world and tried again, and it still failed. Took screenshot but cant put it in a comment.

Comment: Deleteed and then redownloaded minecraft. still there. Do i have to delete or refresh my account or something?

Comment: Never mind, accidenatally changed controls. Sorry for bother.

Comment: Procedurally casting close vote per user90998's answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old bug. All you have to do is restart minecraft to get unstuck. Make some more room around your bed before you go back to sleep the next time.

If that doesn't work, please provide more info about your minecraft installation (version and any mods installed).

Possible duplicate of:
[I am glitching in a bed in Minecraft multiplayer 1.7.2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/139198/i-am-glitching-in-a-bed-in-minecraft-multiplayer-1-7-2)